# 'psxevars command not found' when enabling Intel Fortran

Tags: windows, fortran, intel-fortran

I installed the non-commercial intel Fortran 2018 in Windows 10. According to the starting guide, I should run psxevars.bat. But when I typed 'psxevars' in cmd. It showed 'psxevars command not found'. So I used another way, double clicking it in windows. Then I try ifort in cmd. It doesn't work. It showed 'ifort command not found'. How can I make it work? Btw, I used the cmd in the product group from start menu.

Comment: Welcome, do not say "it does bot work", say what actually happens.

Comment: There should be a compiler startup shortcut in the Windows 10 tile menu which is preset with the right options.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure Visual Studio (e.g. Visual Studio Community 2015 version) is installed before installing Intel Parallel Studio.

After installing Intel Parallel Studio successfully, a "command line prompt" should be listed at the start menu like this:

[image: start menu]

There is no need to run `psxevars.bat` because the installing process has already done this for us.

Another situation might be that we try to use Intel tools in Windows command-line prompt through the `cmd` command. In this case, we need to run `psxevars.bat`. And do not forget to specify two arguments, `arch` and `vs`, as shown in below. 
[image: psxevars.bat arguments]

And notice that it only takes effects in this command-line window, i.e. the same running need to be done for every `cmd` command-line prompt.

an eternal way is to set the environment variable. Add directories containing Intel tool executables to the "PATH" environment variable, and other related things(libs, include).

On Windows, I recommend using Intel Parallel Studio with the Visual Studio IDE.